# How to use AsyncTask correctly in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I don't want to pass any arguments to `doInBackground` method of the AsyncTask.

So what should be the code like?

Comment: try something before you post something... read blogs and developers guide

Comment: You must read.... [click here](https://androidride.com/asynctask-android-tutorial-example/)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AsyncExample extends Activity{


private String url="http://www.google.co.in";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    new AsyncCaller().execute();

}

private class AsyncCaller extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(AsyncExample.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //this method will be running on background thread so don't update UI frome here
        //do your long running http tasks here,you dont want to pass argument and u can access the parent class' variable url over here


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        //this method will be running on UI thread

        pdLoading.dismiss();
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx !
That's look like what I wanted ...  :D

Answer (score 18):

According to [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), its

```
 AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
```

- Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
- Progress, the type of the progress units published during the
  background computation.
- Result, the type of the result of the background computation.

So if you want to pass void in **doInBackground** just pass void in place of Params.

Example code:

```
class DownloadLink extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //Do Your stuff here..
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And call it as:

```
 new DownloadLink().execute();
```

Comment: It means params is the array of tasks and all task's return type is void

Comment: @blackHawk - Yes

Answer (score 9):

Create your `AsyncTask` class as if you don't want to pass any parameter to `doInBackground` :

```
 public class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


          public LongOperation(Context context) {

          }

          @Override
          protected void onPreExecute() {

          }

          @Override
          protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

              return null;
          }      

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(String result) {                           

          }
    }
```

and start AsyncTask as without passing any parameter to execute :

```
   LongOperation longOperation = new LongOperation(this);
   longOperation.execute();
```

Comment: I noticed the Android Studio autocomplete does not give you the "<Void, Void, String>", which can trip you up.  Also, note that the return for `doInBackground` must indeed be the third argument of the class ("String" in the example shown).

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you want to pass any arguments to it? You should explain...

This is how it usually works (example):

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

And to execute it you call:

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

Source: [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Often, parameters are passed to `AsyncTask` but not necessary

Comment: there is no need for me to pass an argument to `doInBakground` .
this method only opens a php file on my web server by POST method . And I only need to get a response from that php file . So I don't need to pass any arguments to `doInBackground`.

Comment: Simple - you just use the `Void` class. So you would have `private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Long> {`.