# How run other process to background?

Tags: android, process, background

Is it possible to run other application (process) to background? I mean that for example I will use intent for starting some other application, but I don't want to make this application running in foreground but in background, it means that application shouldn't be opened but only kept in memory minimized.

Comment: Try using an async task like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250989/how-to-use-asynctask-correctly-android)

Answer (score 0):

If the other Application has an accessible service, you can call startService with an intent that references that service.  This will load the Application if it is not already running.

By "accessible" I mean the manifest for the other application should contain a

<service android:exported=true" ... /> element

Answer (score 0):

You need use service (or intentService) to run something in the background. If you need to display info from it have an activity get its data from the service. if you only use an activity it will be paused and stopped according to the android lifecycle