# How To Use AsynTask In Android?

Tags: android

How Can I Use Asyntask In Android I want to use it For Background Process Like Webservice Call.

Please Any One Have Idea than please tell me.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use AsyncTask correctly - Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250989/how-to-use-asynctask-correctly-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use This
=======
private class SetDataOfWebService extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        // ProgressDialog pDialog;
        boolean success = false;
        ConnectivityManager connectivity;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MailSettings.this);
            // pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait..");
            // pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                success = true;
                //Call WebService

            } else {
                success = false;
            }
            return success;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            // if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing())
            // pDialog.dismiss();
            if (result) {

            //Write Code For PostExcutive
            } else {
                return;
            }

        }

        public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
            connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            if (connectivity != null) {
                NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();

                if (info != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                        Log.i("Class", info[i].getState().toString());
                        if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the **asynctask** this way and dont forget that always do the task that relate to UI in **onPreExecute()** and **onPostExecute()** method.The task that is webservice call or db operation or whatever that you want to perform in differen thread should be in doInBackground() method.

```
class CallWebservice extends AsyncTask<Double, Void, Boolean> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(StudentListActivity.this,
                "Calling Webservice", "Please wait...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Double... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String response = null;

            response = Utillity
                    .getData(WEBSERVICE_URL);
                            return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean flag) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(flag);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

And the create the utility class which having method for https like this:--

```
   Class Utility{
public static String getData(String url) {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header

    HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 10000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 10000);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String temp = "";

    try {

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '+'));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
        temp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Log.i("tag", temp);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return temp;
}
  }
```

And for more info about asynctask please visit the official website http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is good [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html).

In short in some cases you may extend AsyncTask:

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
      String response = "";
      for (String url : urls) {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
          HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
          InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

          BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
          String s = "";
          while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            response += s;
          }

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      textView.setText(result);
    }
  }
```

The `<String, Void, String>` in `AsyncTask` are:

1. Type of parameter that passed into `doInBackground`.
2. Type of value that indicates progress of the task.
3. Type of resulted value.

In `doInBackground` you should execute your 'heavy' calculations. The `onPostExecute` executes on finish of `doInBackground`.

To execute your `AsyncTask` just call `execute(url1, url2, ...)`