# activitythread.performlaunchactivity(activitythread$activityclientrecord intent) line:2305

Tags: android, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

So I am working on an app that is to read in an XML file from a URL. I am getting an issue of no source found. The file that keeps popping up is

activitythread.performlaunchactivity(activitythread$activityclientrecord intent) line:2305

This is my code:

```
package com.lnrpuc.lnrpucseniordesign;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class LightsMainScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lights_main);

        XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;
        try {
            pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser xpp = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();

            URL url = new URL("http://lnrpuc.com/List.xml");
            URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(urlc.getInputStream());

            xpp.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES,false);
            xpp.setInput(is,null);

            parseXML(xpp);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Button returnBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.returnBtn);

        returnBtn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }  

    private void parseXML(XmlPullParser xpp) throws XmlPullParserException,IOException
    {
        ArrayList<Lights> lights = null;
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            Lights lightStatus = null;
            boolean lightsTag = false;
            boolean lightsStatusTag = false;

            while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String currentTag = null;
                switch(eventType){
                case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                    lights = new ArrayList<Lights>();
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    currentTag = xpp.getName();
                    if(currentTag == "Lights"){
                        lightStatus = new Lights();
                        lightsTag = true;   }
                    else if(currentTag == "Status"){
                        lightsStatusTag = true; }
                    else if(currentTag == "a" && lightsTag && lightsStatusTag)  {
                        lightStatus.light1 = xpp.nextText();    }
                    else if(currentTag == "b" && lightsTag && lightsStatusTag)  {
                        lightStatus.light2 = xpp.nextText();    }
                    else if(currentTag == "c" && lightsTag && lightsStatusTag)  {
                        lightStatus.light3 = xpp.nextText();    }
                    else if(currentTag == "d" && lightsTag && lightsStatusTag)  {
                        lightStatus.light4 = xpp.nextText();    }
                    else if(currentTag == "e" && lightsTag && lightsStatusTag)  {
                        lightStatus.light5 = xpp.nextText();    }
                    else if(currentTag == "f" && lightsTag && lightsStatusTag)  {
                        lightStatus.light6 = xpp.nextText();    }
                    else if(currentTag == "g" && lightsTag && lightsStatusTag)  {
                        lightStatus.light7 = xpp.nextText();    }
                    else if(currentTag == "h" && lightsTag && lightsStatusTag)  {
                        lightStatus.light8 = xpp.nextText();    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    currentTag = xpp.getName();
                    if(currentTag.equalsIgnoreCase("status") && lightStatus != null){
                        lights.add(lightStatus);
                        lightsStatusTag = false;    }
                    else if(currentTag.equalsIgnoreCase("lights")){
                        lightsTag = false;  }                       
                    }
                eventType = xpp.next();
                }
            setLights(lights);
        }

    private void setLights(ArrayList<Lights> lights)
    {
        int light_1 = 0, light_2 = 0, light_3 = 0, light_4 = 0,
                light_5 = 0, light_6 = 0, light_7 = 0, light_8 = 0;

        ToggleButton light1Btn = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.light_1);
        ToggleButton light2Btn = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.light_2);
        ToggleButton light3Btn = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.light_3);
        ToggleButton light4Btn = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.light_4);
        ToggleButton light5Btn = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.light_5);
        ToggleButton light6Btn = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.light_6);
        ToggleButton light7Btn = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.light_7);
        ToggleButton light8Btn = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.light_8);

        Iterator<Lights> it = lights.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            Lights lightStatus = (Lights) it.next();
            light_1 = Integer.parseInt(lightStatus.light1);
            light_2 = Integer.parseInt(lightStatus.light2);
            light_3 = Integer.parseInt(lightStatus.light3);
            light_4 = Integer.parseInt(lightStatus.light4);
            light_5 = Integer.parseInt(lightStatus.light5);
            light_6 = Integer.parseInt(lightStatus.light6);
            light_7 = Integer.parseInt(lightStatus.light7);
            light_8 = Integer.parseInt(lightStatus.light8);
        }

        if(light_1 == 1)    {
            light1Btn.setChecked(true);
        } else light1Btn.setChecked(false);
        if(light_2 == 1)    {
            light2Btn.setChecked(true);
        } else light2Btn.setChecked(false);
        if(light_3 == 1)    {
            light3Btn.setChecked(true);
        } else light3Btn.setChecked(false);
        if(light_4 == 1)    {
            light4Btn.setChecked(true);
        } else light4Btn.setChecked(false);
        if(light_5 == 1)    {
            light5Btn.setChecked(true);
        } else light5Btn.setChecked(false);
        if(light_6 == 1)    {
            light6Btn.setChecked(true);
        } else light6Btn.setChecked(false);
        if(light_7 == 1)    {
            light7Btn.setChecked(true);
        } else light7Btn.setChecked(false);
        if(light_8 == 1)    {
            light8Btn.setChecked(true);
        } else light8Btn.setChecked(false);
    }
}

class Lights
{
    public String light1;
    public String light2;
    public String light3;
    public String light4;
    public String light5;
    public String light6;
    public String light7;
    public String light8;
}
```

I am new to Android programming and don't know where the issue comes in.

```
    02-01 22:48:10.628: W/ActivityThread(14211): Application com.lnrpuc.lnrpucseniordesign is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
02-01 22:48:10.628: I/System.out(14211): Sending WAIT chunk
02-01 22:48:10.768: I/dalvikvm(14211): Debugger is active
02-01 22:48:10.828: I/System.out(14211): Debugger has connected
02-01 22:48:10.828: I/System.out(14211): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-01 22:48:11.028: I/System.out(14211): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-01 22:48:11.239: I/System.out(14211): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-01 22:48:11.439: I/System.out(14211): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-01 22:48:11.639: I/System.out(14211): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-01 22:48:11.839: I/System.out(14211): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-01 22:48:12.039: I/System.out(14211): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-01 22:48:12.230: I/System.out(14211): debugger has settled (1310)
02-01 22:48:19.597: D/AndroidRuntime(14211): Shutting down VM
02-01 22:48:19.597: W/dalvikvm(14211): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417c0898)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lnrpuc.lnrpucseniordesign/com.lnrpuc.lnrpucseniordesign.LightsMainScreen}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1144)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at com.lnrpuc.lnrpucseniordesign.LightsMainScreen.onCreate(LightsMainScreen.java:38)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
02-01 22:48:19.658: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    ... 11 more
```

---

---

Update:
I changed to using an AsyncTask instead of the previous configuration and I am now receiving thread errors. I'm not sure why it is throwing the errors.

LightsMainScreen.java

```
package com.lnrpuc.lnrpucseniordesign;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.lnrpuc.lnrpucseniordesign.LightTest1;

public class LightsMainScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lights_main);

        Button returnBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.returnBtn);
        ToggleButton light3Btn = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.light_3);

        light3Btn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                new UpdateXML().execute();  }   }   )   ;

        returnBtn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();   }   }   )   ;
    }

    private class UpdateXML extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
    {
        ToggleButton light3Btn = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.light_3);

        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            if(light3Btn.isChecked()) LightTest1.XMLUpdate("1", "3", "1");
            else LightTest1.XMLUpdate("1", "3", "0");
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute()  {}

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        protected void onProgressUpdate()   {}
    }
}
```

LightTest1.java

```
package com.lnrpuc.lnrpucseniordesign;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;

import com.lnrpuc.Services.GetNamesRequestType;
import com.lnrpuc.Services.GetNamesResponseType;
import com.lnrpuc.Services.GetStatusRequestType;
import com.lnrpuc.Services.GetStatusResponseType;
import com.lnrpuc.Services.HomeAutomationServicePortTypeProxy;
import com.lnrpuc.Services.SetStatusRequestType;
import com.lnrpuc.Services.SetStatusResponseType;


public class LightTest1 {

    public static void XMLUpdate(String object, String number, String status){
        try {
            HomeAutomationServicePortTypeProxy proxy = new HomeAutomationServicePortTypeProxy();

            //names request
            //GetNamesRequestType inGNRT = new GetNamesRequestType();
            //inGNRT.setPass("12345");

            //GetNamesResponseType outGNRT = proxy.getNames(inGNRT);
            //System.out.println(outGNRT.get_return());

            //status request
            //GetStatusRequestType inGSRT = new GetStatusRequestType();
            //inGSRT.setPass("12345");

            //GetStatusResponseType outGSRT = proxy.getStatus(inGSRT);
            //System.out.println(outGSRT.get_return());

            //set status
            SetStatusRequestType inSSRT = new SetStatusRequestType();
            inSSRT.setPass("12345");
            inSSRT.setObject(object);
            inSSRT.setNumber(number);
            inSSRT.setStatus(status);

            SetStatusResponseType outSSRT = proxy.setStatus(inSSRT);
            System.out.println(outSSRT.get_return());


        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("failed");
        }


    }
}
```

LogCat Output

```
02-06 13:53:38.759: I/dalvikvm(16012): Failed resolving Lcom/lnrpuc/Services/HomeAutomationServicePortType; interface 93 'Ljava/rmi/Remote;'
02-06 13:53:38.759: W/dalvikvm(16012): Link of class 'Lcom/lnrpuc/Services/HomeAutomationServicePortType;' failed
02-06 13:53:38.759: I/dalvikvm(16012): Failed resolving Lcom/lnrpuc/Services/HomeAutomationServicePortTypeProxy; interface 30 'Lcom/lnrpuc/Services/HomeAutomationServicePortType;'
02-06 13:53:38.759: W/dalvikvm(16012): Link of class 'Lcom/lnrpuc/Services/HomeAutomationServicePortTypeProxy;' failed
02-06 13:53:38.759: E/dalvikvm(16012): Could not find class 'com.lnrpuc.Services.HomeAutomationServicePortTypeProxy', referenced from method com.lnrpuc.lnrpucseniordesign.LightTest1.XMLUpdate
02-06 13:53:38.759: W/dalvikvm(16012): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 31 (Lcom/lnrpuc/Services/HomeAutomationServicePortTypeProxy;) in Lcom/lnrpuc/lnrpucseniordesign/LightTest1;
02-06 13:53:38.759: D/dalvikvm(16012): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
02-06 13:53:38.759: W/dalvikvm(16012): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 94 (Ljava/rmi/RemoteException;)
02-06 13:53:38.759: W/dalvikvm(16012): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x26
02-06 13:53:38.759: W/dalvikvm(16012): VFY:  rejected Lcom/lnrpuc/lnrpucseniordesign/LightTest1;.XMLUpdate (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
02-06 13:53:38.759: W/dalvikvm(16012): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x0026
02-06 13:53:38.769: W/dalvikvm(16012): VFY:  rejected Lcom/lnrpuc/lnrpucseniordesign/LightTest1;.XMLUpdate (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
02-06 13:53:38.769: W/dalvikvm(16012): Verifier rejected class Lcom/lnrpuc/lnrpucseniordesign/LightTest1;
02-06 13:53:38.769: W/dalvikvm(16012): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417c0898)
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012): Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: com/lnrpuc/lnrpucseniordesign/LightTest1
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012):    at com.lnrpuc.lnrpucseniordesign.LightsMainScreen$UpdateXML.doInBackground(LightsMainScreen.java:41)
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012):    at com.lnrpuc.lnrpucseniordesign.LightsMainScreen$UpdateXML.doInBackground(LightsMainScreen.java:1)
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012):    ... 3 more
```

Comment: I re-ran the application and now I am receiving a bunch of errors in my logcat.

Comment: I edited and posted them above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing network operations on the main UI thread that is why your app is crashing. Do not do network operations in the onCreate method.

Create an async task and perform the network operations in a background thread

Check these links for more info

[How to use AsyncTask correctly in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250989/how-to-use-asynctask-correctly-android)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Ok I will try that out. Thanks I'll let you know what happens