# cannot fetch text from a file on a website android

Tags: android, android-internet

I am trying to fetch text from a simple text file uploaded on a website accessible directly with the link i've used in my code but for some reason its not working. Using debug tool i found out that its throwing an exception after HttpResponse line. I have no idea how to solve this problem.(sorry for my long question, i'm new to android and stackoverflow)

```
package com.example.trial;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    TextView TextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(
                    "http://www.androidworkshopmit.webs.com/abc.txt");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

            BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);

            InputStream is = buf.getContent();

            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line + "\n");
            }
            TextView.setText(total);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("hi, there is some error!");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: The answers are correct. If you read what the error is called its called NetworkOnMainThreadException. Pretty obvious what that means. No network on main thread allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My code but for some reason its not working. Using debug tool i found out that its throwing an exception after HttpResponse line.

You are doing your the Network Operations (`HTTP GET` calls) on your main UI thread. Do all the network calls in the background thread using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Here is basic example of how to use it: [How to use AsyncTask correctly in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250989/how-to-use-asynctask-correctly-android)