# Use roster entries to chat with Smack and Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, xmpp, smack

I am trying to figure out a way to use the roster i get as described in the Smack documentation but i want to be able to select the user and move to another activity for the 1-1 chat. I can retrieve the roster fine, but how can i create some kind of a list with these users? I've been searching for some time but cannot find something like that when using the Android Studio.

Closest post i found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28559752/get-online-usersroster-entries-using-smack-4-1-in-android).

But i want to be able to select from the users and create another activity using the user selected and create a chat session. Any help appreciated!