# How to retrieve data from background in Android App

Tags: java, android, database, firebase

There is 1 `Button` on my `MainActivity` and when user clicks on it, it starts the `UserProfileActivity` to view the current signed in user profile details along with names (values) on `TextView`.

e.g. it's something like this >>

"Name: Bean Smith",

" Age: 27 ", 

" Gender: Male ".

 I've already created the layout for the same and I know how to retrieve data's from the `DatabaseReference` to display values on `TextView` acting as the user details (from DataSnapShot). 
Issue:
I want to load the user details before my `MainActivity` will start, so that when the user clicks on the button to check the user profile, the values should get auto populate automatically.

I've searched and found `AsyncTask` but I Don't really know how or when to use this. please any help from you guys will be highly appreciated..

thanks.

Comment: You are confused using `AsyncTask`. See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250989/how-to-use-asynctask-correctly-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have two screens, A and B, or you want that when screen B opens, it starts with filled data, use the following logic.

Firstly, when you are going from one activity to another, that time load all data on screen A and pass the data to screen B by intent, and get or check the received intent values using this, you can achieve your destination:

**In class A**

```
Intent intent=new Intent(A.this,B.class); 
intent.putExtra("data","data_value");
startActivity(intent);
```

**In class B**

```
if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
{
    String a=getIntent().getStringExtra("data").toString();
}
```

as follow you can send multiple data over the two screens.

Comment: thanks!! it makes a lot of sense to me now ( that's the exact solution to my problem, now I'm out of confusion  thanks!!! ). I'm already using SharedPrefences from class A to store the datas gotten from my firebase database & when class B gets opened, it gets the class A SharedPrefences and update the class B views that needs to be updated with it's required data, still I added real-time checking in class B so class A won't only be the one responsible for updating the SharedPrefences. ( thanks!!!! )

Comment: please upvote(click on top button) it that would help me to increase my reputation

Comment: I've tried it already but Stackoverflow said I need the minimum of 10 reputation to upvote the answer

Comment: Thanks to support me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things,

1. As Mayank Garg said you can download the data using AsyncTask task in MainActivity and pass them to other activity but in this case u have to be careful about the null checks.
2. You can write it Sqlite Database and retrieve it back from 2nd Activity.

Comment: As you mention the 2 option: it is more complicated and give more time and space complexity.