# Use of suspend function in android splash screen

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, coroutine, kotlinx.coroutines

My app splash screen is use to fetch data from network and after data fetch is success, I want to send user to Home screen. Usually, we use Thread.sleep or Handler to stay on Splash screen for some time. Can we do this using suspend function of Kotlin?

Comment: `launch(UI) { showSplash(); delay(someSeconds); sendUserToHomeScreen() }`

Comment: Hi, if your app is an android app, please add "android" tag to your question.

Comment: Can we use it without delay? For example, all data are fetch in 1sec and we have put delay of 3sec, so there is wastage of 2sec.

Comment: Yes you can start the API call in onCreate, then wait for the response and then navigate the user to home screen .

Comment: I am calling API in onCreate, but I want to know how to use suspend function of kotlin or async/await in koltin so that I can navigate to other screen as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Anko`, it is simple and clear, and your owner is JetBrains

#### Step 1. Getting anko

Put it on your `app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:0.10.5"
    ...
}
```

#### Step 2. Using anko

Inside of your `SplashActivity`, on your `onCreate()` try as follow

```
doAsync {
    val result = URL("your request here").readText()
    //depending of your result go to MainActivity
}
```

See more about `Anko` [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko)

Comment: Can we solve it using kotlin co-routine library(experimental)? Using suspend function on network call.

Comment: How about without anko?

Comment: @JPM, you can use `AsyncTask`, see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14251115/6733404)

Comment: I'd rather stick with the future and use coroutines, we are not using anko right now so need a solution for just coroutines.  I've been looking at a few but the library keeps changing and all the solutions out there are old.

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with Kotlin in Android, a library we can’t miss is [Anko](https://antonioleiva.com/anko-background-kotlin-android/).

Here i added snippet of code

```
async {
    val result = URL("<api call>").readText()
    uiThread { 
        Log.d("Request", result)
        longToast("Request performed") 
    }
}
```

or else you can go with plain AsyncTask

```
class GetWeatherAsyncTask : AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>() {

    override fun onPreExecute() {
        // Before doInBackground
    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Params?): Progress {
        // ...
        publishProgress(progressResult)

        return result
    }

    override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: Progress?) {
       // use progressResult to do things such as updating UI...
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: Result?) {
        // Done: use result which is returned from doInBackground()
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, AsyncTask is also a way, but I want to do it with the basic kotlin co-routine library (experimental one), to understand deeply how co-routine works