# Read html code of website using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have cleaned and rebuild my code as well but still the issue is not solved.

Below is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String result = null;
        String stringUrl = "https://www.ecowebhosting.co.uk/";
        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

        downloadTask.execute(stringUrl);
    }

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                //It is like opening a browser
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                int data = reader.read();
                while (data != -1) {
                    char currentChar = (char) data;
                    result = result + currentChar;
                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return result;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Failed";
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            Log.i("Results",s);
        }
    }
}
```

The code is running fine but nothing is printed in the logs. The following is the log:

[image: screenshot of the logs]

Comment: Check the [AsyncTask example code](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask). It is the `onPostExecute` part that I would recommend.

Comment: i have updated the code using onPostExecute() but still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask` is an asynchronous process. So when you call `Log.i("Result:", result);`, the AsyncTask is not finished and `result` is still empty.

You should print your result from `onPostExecute()` method.
You can look on [this page](http://%20https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)).

Here is some examples on how to implement an `AsyncTask` correctly:

- https://www.upwork.com/hiring/mobile/why-you-should-use-asynctask-in-android-development/
- [How to use AsyncTask correctly in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250989/how-to-use-asynctask-correctly-in-android)

Best

Comment: I have added the onPostExecute as well but still doesn't work.

Comment: How did you do it ?

Comment: @Maxoulli i have updated the code.please look into it

Comment: What's going on if you print the result inside `doInBackground()` ? It is empty too ?

Comment: You should look at @Mukul answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You only have to change code inside your doInBackGround

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result;
        String inputLine;
        try {
            URL myUrl = new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection)
                    myUrl.openConnection();
            connection.setReadTimeout(150000); 
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000); 
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect();
            InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
            //Create a new buffered reader and String Builder
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            //Check if the line we are reading is not null
            while((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
            }
            //Close our InputStream and Buffered reader
            reader.close();
            streamReader.close();
            //Set our result equal to our stringBuilder
            result = stringBuilder.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "error";
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        Log.i("Results",s);
    }
}
```

Comment: My code works in my friends PC but doesnt work in my PC .Thats why i posted this question

Comment: Yes i tried this code is also giving nothing in the logs