# SearchView online search

Tags: java, android

How can i Use SearchView to perform an online search within my App, and presenting the result in a ListView 
using such query: https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=android&maxResults=10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SearchView inside xml then get the reference to that object and set a listener and do network call after receiving the query.

```
 searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String txt) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String txt) {

            //Do network call from here.
            doSearch(txt);

            return false;
        }
    });

  void doSearch(String query){
   String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q="+query+"&maxResults=10";
    ....
  }
```

Comment: how can i use this with AsynTasck class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250989/how-to-use-asynctask-correctly-in-android